# div text to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Scenario :
After double quote,next characters were not displaying.

I know this is because of escaping of single and double quotes, I have tried this regex `(/"/g,'\"')`, but its not working.

Can someone help me review the code?My wanted output is that all characters on div should also display on input.

PS: I want to avoid `replace(/"/g,'&quot;')` as much as possible.

```
 <div>single ' double " single ' </div>

<form>
</form>    

$("form").append('<input type="text" value = "' + $("div").text().replace(/"/g,'\"') + '" />');
```

see this Fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3uc4fLeh/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/3uc4fLeh/5/)):

```
$('<input>', {
    type: 'text',
    value : $("div").text()
}).appendTo('form');
```

---

Update: for multiple elements, try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/3uc4fLeh/11/))

```
var txt = $('div').text();

$('<tr><td><input type="button"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>')
    .appendTo('table')
    .find('input')
    .val( txt );
```

Comment: If I need to add other element, is this the proper format? http://jsfiddle.net/3uc4fLeh/9/

Comment: jQuery's [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) does support that format (`.append( content [, content ] )`); but honestly, for me, it makes it hard to read. You could just make another copy of the above code to add a second input.

Comment: format become complicated if like this http://jsfiddle.net/3uc4fLeh/10/. Any other idea? Anyways,thanks for that info !that one is new to me. @Mottie

Comment: please see thishttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576216/dynamic-input-name-with-double-quotes-issue