# Dynamic input name with double quotes issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

Scenario : When `<div>` text has double quote. JQuery method to append dynamic input and to alert the value of input is not working. I know this issue trigger when escaping quotes. Can someone review the code?

```js
var divText = $("div").text();
$('form:not(:has([name="' + divText + '"]))').append($('<input>', {
  type: 'text',
  value: divText,
  name: divText
}));
alert($('[name="' + divText + '"]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>"</div>
<form>

</form>
```

I've created some [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h218ptt5/3/) here

Comment: You really should put the code in the question.

Comment: You are going to have to escape it ND YOU re going to run into more problems https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: @epascarello I have tried `$("div").text().replace(/"/g,'\"') ` but no works

Comment: You need to escape the slash try `'\\"'`

Comment: escaping along wont help, well might work but its not how it should be, you setting the name attribute of input element to text inside the div, attributes like name, id should not have any spaces or special character in it. Change your logic there..

Comment: @epascarello ,I really need to work with special characters for input name ttribute

Comment: @bumbumpaw Did you look at my answer?

Comment: @epascarello, yes, i'm just testing and studying it sir.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use double quotes, you can remove them like so:

```
var divText = $("div").text().replace(/"/g, '');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/h218ptt5/6/)

Comment: I dont want to replace any char with nothing, div text should also be the name of the input,regardless of what it has.

Answer (score 0):

Playing off the reg exp from the jQuery docs

```js
var divText = $("div").text();
var name = divText.replace(/("|:|\.|\[|\]|,)/g, "\\$1");
$('form:not(:has([name="' + name + '"]))').append($('<input>', {
  type: 'text',
  value: divText,
  name: divText
}));
alert($('[name="' + divText + '"]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>"</div>
<form>

</form>
```